# SASS: Is there a way to calculate an attribute based on a number in the class name?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using Angular Grid.  I have a data table, where data is nested in rows, and the number of nested row levels depends on the data at any given time.  Therefore, I have CSS classes, such as:

.ag-row-level-1

.ag-row-level-2

.ag-row-level-3

etc

I don't know ahead of item how many potential row-levels there will be, and I would like to apply padding depending on the row-level.  Is it possible, in SCSS/SASS to do something like:

.ag-row-level-$level {
   padding-left: $level*20 px
}

where the selector identifies all classes that start .ag-row-level- and padding-left is then calculated based on the actual row level in the class name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. Something like this works:

```
@for $i from 1 through …
  .ag-row-#{$i}
    padding-left: $i * 20px
```

Replace the … with the maximum number to support. This should really suffice for anything you want to do regarding this example.

## Why is this feature not in SASS?

Well SASS is a CSS-Preprocessor. Not more. That means that the Sass-compiler generates valid CSS from it and CSS doesn't have that feature. Since that compiler has no idea about the HTML (and really, there isn't a good way to find out, since there are tons of HTML-generating technologies) it cannot possibly generate all the needed CSS.

## But this isn't enough

Well you can circumvent the problem using Javascript. It is rather unnecessary and I would recommend going with the first example for your case, but if that doesn't work, you can do something like this:

```js
function parseLevels() {
  /* call this function whenever you need to update it */
  const paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-row');
  for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; ++i) {
    paragraphs[i].style.paddingLeft = (20 * paragraphs[i].dataset.level) + "px";
  }
}

parseLevels();
```

```html
<div class="ag-row" data-level="1">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="2">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="3">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="4">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="5">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="4">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="5">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="3">lorem</div>
<div class="ag-row" data-level="10">lorem</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you so much!  I used the first option.